# Batch convert text files from LF line endings to CRLF

Tags: git, dos2unix

I have a vb.net (visual studio 2010) project that is version controlled with git (1.7.10.msysgit.1). I made a mistake of leaving `core.autocrlf` to true in git. Now I have set `core.autocrlf` to false, but the source code is already converted to LF line endings inside the repository. I want to change the line endings back to CRLF.

My plan to correct the situation is:

1. git clone
2. delete all source code files in the clone
3. git checkout -f
4. convert all LF to CRLF
5. git commit
6. git pull from the original repo

I am having problem with step 4. There are a lot of files in the project and hopefully there is a tool to batch convert all text files into CRLF line endings.

I have tried `dos2unix` that is available in the git bash, but looks like it will not process subfolders and it told me that the text files `looks binary`.

So, what is the best way to batch convert my source code back to CRLF line endings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed the obvious way:

1. git clone to folder A. git config core.autocrlf false
2. git clone to folder B. git config core.autocrlf true
3. delete all source files from folder B
4. git checkout -f in folder B
5. cut and paste all files and folders from folder B to folder A
6. git commit in folder A
7. git pull from the original repository

Answer (score 8):

I took Endy's steps but reduced it to just using one single repository:

```
1. git config core.autocrlf true
2. delete all files in your working tree (except the .git folder for sure)
3. git checkout -f
4. git config core.autocrlf false
5. git commit -am "corrected all line endings from LF to CRLF"
```

Comment: Nice! But be careful if you have ignored / untracked files.

Answer (score 2):

Christoph's answer almost worked for us but for some reason git missed a bunch of files. (We're on version 2.20). We had to force git to rescan everything via "git read-tree --empty". After doing this, some files showed as "delete" which was incorrect, but after a reset and add that worked for us.

```
1. git config core.autocrlf true
2. delete all files in your working tree (except the .git folder for sure)
3. git checkout -f
4. git config core.autocrlf false
5. git read-tree --empty
6. git add .
7. git reset
8. git add .
9. git commit -m "corrected all line endings from LF to CRLF"
```